# How to improve accuracy of tesseract engine on my images?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I use tesseract engine to OCR my images as below.
[image1 to OCR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxRQI.png)
[image2 to OCR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKWZ8.png)

I used eng lang and have configured the engine with a white list of chars: "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

```
pOCREngine->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
```

The accuracy is not good, around 10% or so. I have tried to train the engine with ~200 of such images and combine the trained data with eng+mytrainedfont. The accuracy was not improved.

Does anyone have any idea to improve OCR of such images? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

The images you provided are difficult to get a 100% accuracy on when I tried it. To improve tesseract ocr you will need to apply some image processing methods.
I used a Gaussian filter on both and used a Maximum filter after that to reduce the noise. After that I made the images binary.

I'm using tesseract ocr in c++ and I'm using OpenCV libraries for image processing. I tested the following images with the following results:

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcZJo.jpg)
**result:** ***yfsxf***

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1477.jpg)
**result:** ***26ww(***

Hope this gives you an idea on how to improve tesseract results. Unfortunately the images you provided are a bit tough to read with tesseract.